# Printing a simple matrix in python using nested for loops

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my assignment.

Print out a 3x3 matrix of “-”s using for loops.

It should look like this:

```
- - -
- - -
- - -
```

This is the closest I have come but it's not working

```
x = "-"
for i in range(3):
    for n in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            print x,
```

You will need nested for loops to accomplish this.

I have been trying this for an hour with no luck,  can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show your code or no one will help you

Comment: We are not here to answer your assignments. Edit: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's the closest you got in that hour? Show code and output.

Comment: What i have done so far is this >>> x = "-"
>>> for i in range(3):
 for n in range(3):
  for x in range(3):
   print x,

Comment: What output are you getting? Also, is there any reason for you to be using three loops? At most you should only need two.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(21/7):
   print ' '.join(['-' for _ in range(264/88)])
```

Comment: are you taking the micky?! `21/7` why not `3` ?

Comment: >.> this is amusingly hilarious, also does the job painfully

Comment: You may as well go the whole hog with `838.5 / 279.5`

Comment: I think I will always do this now in any answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `x` is defined to be `-`, so you shouldn't enumerate over it.
I edited your code to produce a working version.

Note that in the internal loop you need to put spaces between the `-`, while in the external loop you want to move to the next line.

Here is the code for python 3:

```
x = "-" 
for i in range(3): 
    for n in range(3): 
        print(x, end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

Here is the code for python 2:

```
x = "-" 
for i in range(3): 
    for n in range(3): 
        print x,
    print('\n')
```

Comment: @Bryan see my edit. The print statement in python 2 and 3 has a bit different format, so I added the python 2 version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Very good start!

Let's think through, what were you trying to achieve with your 3rd loop.
(Hint: you don't need a third loop).

If you talk out what you need to happen it becomes:

1) print a "- " three times.  (inner loop)
2) print a new line
3) now go back and repeat steps 1) and 2) three times  (outer loop)

That would only be 2 loops, not 3.

Try This:

```
x = "- "
for i in range(3):
    for n in range(3):
        print x,
    print "\n"
```

You could even shorten this to

```
for i in range(3):       # print the following line 3 times
    for n in range(3):   # print 3 dashes, separated by a space
        print "- ",
    print "\n"           # begin a new line
```

BTW, `print x,` is proper if using Python 2, but for Python 3, it will need to be changed to `print(x, end='')`.

Comment: Your output doesn't have the same format as the OP wanted.

Comment: Can you check, I think I edited it after your comment, perhaps, but before I noticed your comment.  If so, you are correct that I had left the newline off, and the space between each dash.

Comment: When I run your code on python 2, All the '-' form a vertical line (with a space between every 3), instead of 3 horizontal lines.

Comment: You need to add a "," after the print statement if you want to stay in the same line. That is: print "- ",

Comment: @MiriamFarber: my bad,  thanks for the reminder !  I Shall fix now..!

Answer (score 0):

construct a matrix using nested loop:

```
matrix = [[],[],[]]

for x in range(0,3):
  for y in range(0,3):
    matrix[x].append("-")
```

then print it:

```
for i in range(3):
  print(matrix[i])
```

Comment: Needs to a nested loop

Comment: my mentor wants me to use nested loops

Answer (score -1):

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]

def print_matrix(matrix):
    print("----------------------")
    for k in matrix:
        print("| ", end = "")
        for l in k:
            print ( l, end = " ")
        print("|")
    print("----------------------")

print_matrix(matrix)
```

Comment: This doesn’t match the expected output. The OP didn’t mention these `-----` lines nor `|` between cells, and they want to print `-`'s, not the content of an array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).